# vue-router back() not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I create an extension for Chrome, and I use Vue and Vue-router in it.

To navigate through the pages I use `router.push()`, and it works fine. The problem is that I do not work the transition back.

```
<template>
<a href="#" class="left" @click="back">
  <i class="icon-fontello-left"></i>
</a>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    back(){
      console.log('back click, current', this.$router.currentRoute);
      this.$router.back();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I click on the console `back click, current Object {name: undefined, meta: Object, path: "/settings", hash: "", query: Object…}`, but no transition occurs, and no errors.

I tried different options:

```
this.$router.back()
this.$router.go(-1)
```

but none of them works

Versions:

```
"vue-router": "^2.7.0",
"vue": "^2.4.1"
```

Comment: Have you tried manually manipulating the history API to see what happens?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API It also seems that you need to set permissions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history I am not sure on that one though, might help to read it.

Comment: you are right, I needed to add permission "history", and now everything works

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually manipulating the history API to see what happens?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

It also seems that you might need to set permissions:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history I am not sure on that one though, might help to read it.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry, I was wrong. Adding history to the permissions did not solve the problem. And manual input `window.history.back()` or `window.history.go(-1)` also does not give effect

Comment: No errors? Also please check if you history is actually manipulated even though nothing might happen visually.

Comment: yes, no errors. Yes, I switch to this settings page with `this.$router.push('/settings')`